# How would I properly convert this string to a date (Postgres)?

Tags: postgresql, date, postgresql-9.1

I have the following date string in Postgres:

> Fri 10/8/21 7:30 PM

I need to convert this to a date in Postgres that would display as 2021-10-08. How would I go about doing this?

I've tried `DATE('Fri 10/8/21 7:30 PM')` and I get the following error:

> SQL Error [22007]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "Fri 10/8/21 7:30 PM"

Comment: Per [Data Type Formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html); `select to_date('Fri 10/8/21 7:30 PM', 'Dy MM/DD/YY'); 2021-10-08`. That assumes that [Datestyle](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) has output set to `ISO`.

Comment: 1) You should not be storing dates as strings but as `date` type. 2) This `Fri 10/8/21 7:30 PM` is a timestamp not a date.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [@Adrian Klaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver), that's a [`timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html) for which [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-formatting.html) sounds best: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/FzLSwKVY)

```sql
create table my_table(date_as_string text);
insert into my_table values ('Fri 10/8/21 7:30 PM');

alter table my_table 
  add column just_the_date    date,
  add column just_the_time    time,
  add column proper_timestamp timestamp;

update my_table set 
  just_the_date    = to_date(     date_as_string,'Dy MM/DD/YY'),
  just_the_time    = to_timestamp(date_as_string,'Dy MM/DD/YY HH:MI PM')::time,
  proper_timestamp = to_timestamp(date_as_string,'Dy MM/DD/YY HH:MI PM');

select * from my_table;
--   date_as_string    | just_the_date | just_the_time |  proper_timestamp
-----------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------------
-- Fri 10/8/21 7:30 PM | 2021-10-08    | 19:30:00      | 2021-10-08 19:30:00
```

Refer to [this table in the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) for details on constructing the formatting pattern.

If you only plan to use the date part, consider saving the timestamp separately anyway. You could also hold one column with just the `date`, another one with only `time`, which you could later combine into a full `timestamp` when needed:

```sql
select just_the_date + just_the_time as date_plus_time,
       pg_typeof(just_the_date + just_the_time)
from my_table;
--   date_plus_time    |          pg_typeof
-----------------------+-----------------------------
-- 2021-10-08 19:30:00 | timestamp without time zone
```

Also, it might be a good idea to [upgrade](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/): version 9.1 is no longer supported for quite a while. The latest, [15.3, just came out](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/postgresql-153-148-1311-1215-and-1120-released-2637/).